# Cómo filtrar por mes registros de una tabla SQL

Tags: sql

estos son los datos de mi tabla SQL:

```
Tabla envios
ID proveedor, id componente, idarticulo, cantidad, fecha
    (1,'C1',100,100,'01/04/2013'),
    (2,'C2',200,200,'03/11/2013'),
    (3,'C3',300,300,'05/07/2013'),
    (4,'C4',400,400,'21/09/2013'),
    (5,'C5',500,5000,'11/10/2013'),
    (6,'C6',600,4560,'10/10/2013'),
    (7,'C7',700,100,'20/10/2013'),
    (8,'C8',800,200,'09/10/2013'),
    (9,'C9',900,300,'20/08/2013'),
    (1,'C10',1000,400,'30/04/2013'),
    ...
```

Y tengo que realizar esta consulta "Cuantos envíos se realizaron en el mes 
 de diciembre"

Comment: Y cuál es el nombre de la tabla?, cuáles son los nombres de las columnas?, qué motor de bases de datos estás usando?

Comment: por favor mira [ask]. tu pregunta no se entiende.. ademas tenes que agregar que intentaste hasta ahora que no funciono. La consulta que estas pidiendo es bastante simple.

Comment: Mi tabla se llama Envios, en lo que respecta necesito contar cuantos envios se realizaron en el mes de diciembre, estoy usando el sql server 2014 , intente con datepart, month, getdate. y no se, la consulta pueda ser simple, sin embargo me estoy iniciando en base de datos y no se mucho aun,

Comment: Agrega toda esa informacion en la pregunta. Muestra los querys que probaste y que error te dieron. usa el boton [edit] y agrega toda esa info en la pregunta

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El tipo `DATE` sirve para almacenar de manera eficiente la fecha. La función `MONTH()` sirve para devolver el mes en un int

Cambia `compodate` por la columna que sea del campo

**Editado:**

```
SELECT COUNT(compodate) FROM envios WHERE MONTH(campodate) = 12
```

Comment: Esto no devuelve cuantos en diciembre, que de hecho es lo que pregunta el OP

Comment: Es importante antes de responder entender qué motor de base de datos ( y versión) se está usando. Hay muchas funciones en SQL (como `MONTH()`) que no son comunes entre motores de bases de datos

Comment: En general, hay algunas preguntas que no deben ser respondidas hasta tanto OP no clarifique que busca y necesita. Y no demuestre, que intento algo.

Comment: Emití en mi cabeza la palabra "contar" :S

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT COUNT(1) Total_Envios, SUM(Cantidad) Total_Cantidad FROM envios WHERE MONTH(fecha) = 12
```

Supongo que para tu datos estadísticos necesitaras tanto la cantidad total de envíos, como la cantidad de artículos enviados.

Comment: Genial... Muchisimas gracias, si me dio lkos recultados, y gracias a todos por las recomendaciones, a la soguiente hare una publicacion mas concreta. les agradesco bastante.

Comment: Para qué sirve el 1 en el COUNT()?

Comment: Es lo mismo que usar cualquier campo, se tiene la idea de que el 1 es mas optimo que usar un campo o un * pero si no estoy mal depende del motor y versión. Pero básicamente es lo mismo que usar COUNT(CAMPO), COUNT(*)

Comment: Corrijo COUNT(1) Y COUNT(*) es lo mismo, pero ambos son mas óptimos que COUNT(CAMPO) .
Es lo que pude entender de acá
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/what-is-the-difference-between-select-count-and-select-countany-non-null-col/2512#2512